# how to locate a column in other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just loaded some tables to our main db.
there is a col in one table called
MAPCONCEPTID. the schema is OPTC and prefix is SNO

the boss is asking me where is this mapped to? which other table that uses this col. it apparently is very important col.

Want to know how to find where MAPCONCEPTID field in one of your table is mapped to

Comment: Um....what are you asking us?  Maybe you want to know if other tables have a column named `MAPCONCEPTID`?

Comment: With this question I'm confuses as you are. So you want to know how to find where MAPCONCEPTID field in one of your table is mapped to?

Comment: So you want to know how to find where MAPCONCEPTID field in one of your table is mapped to? yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL Server Management Studio`, expand the `Tables` node in `Object Explorer` window. Locate your table. Then right-click on it and select `View Dependencies` from the popup menu.

[image]

This will open the `Object Dependencies` window. Use this window to find what other tables it is dependent upon, or what other tables depend on this table.

[image]

Comment: so i am finding it has no dependencies.

Comment: Use the option buttons to find both ways. Which other tables depend on your table, and which tables your table is dependent upon.

Comment: Doesn't this rely on a correctly set up set of keys and relationships between the tables?  Not all developers are lucky enough to walk into a well-built database ...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to start with: this has the advantage of not relying on correctly mapped dependencies and keys, but the **MAJOR** disadvantage of relying on the column in the other table being named the same thing.  It might work for you.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'MAPCONCEPTID' AND -- Your Column Name
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'OPTC' AND -- Your Schema (optional)
    TABLE_NAME != '' -- Exclude the starting table
```